# Dynamic Load of Heatmap Data based on Map Bounds, Performance Issue

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

I have implemented a simple page that uses a listener to determine when a google maps bounds have changed because of zoom or pan. I am dynamically loading json data for a weighted heatmap summarized by the area visible in the map. It is working all except for the fact that I am not properly clearing the previous data from the heatmap on each call to the listener. Performance begins to degrade after the 4th or 5th call to fetch new data. I tried setting heatmap to null. What else is needed to maintain performance?

```
    var map, heatmap;
    var heatMapData = [];

    function initMap() {

        var uluru = { lat: 32.673363, lng: -97.399290 };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: uluru

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function () {
            heatmap = null;
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            //TODO: implement async request
            var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
            var boxRequest = 'HeatMapData?lmin=' + bounds.f.f + '&lmax=' + bounds.f.b + '&lnmin=' + bounds.b.b + '&lnmax=' + bounds.b.f;
            Httpreq.open("GET", boxRequest, false);
            Httpreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
            var heatMapJSON = Httpreq.responseText;

            heatMapData = [];
            var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(heatMapJSON);
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) {
                heatMapData.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(parsedJSON[i].Lat, parsedJSON[i].Lon), weight: parsedJSON[i].weight })
            };
            console.info('map points: ' + parsedJSON.length.toString());

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: heatMapData,
                map : map
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (heatmap != null) {
     heatmap.setMap(null);
};
```